# I have deleted main file from my source file and i got error

Tags: ios7

In iOS 7 I have deleted my main file from my source file. I replaced it from trash and I got an error like this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

how to overcome? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you restored the main.m file did you add it to the bundle? Did you add it with the check mark on copy?

Check in Build Phases under Compile Sources that your main.m file is there.

Also make sure the main file isn't twice in your project.

Comment: What helped you in your case? Build phases or the bundle?